# Regex find string and delete whole line

Tags: python, regex, string

How can I search for a text and if matched delete the entire line, preferably in regex.

What I have tried so far:

My file:

```
wait                    => '10',
```

Trial one

```
data = re.sub(r"^.*wait.*$","",data) #does not work
```

Trial two:

```
data = re.sub(r".+/wait/.+","",data) #does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `regexp` is not correct. Try this:

```
import re
print re.sub(".*wait.*\n",'',"""wait                    => '10',
wait                    => '10',
Other data
wait                    => '10',
""",flags=re.M)
```

---

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M

`re.M`

`re.MULTILINE`

When specified, the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character '$' matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, '^' matches only at the beginning of the string, and '$' only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry. Let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks! (the * in my re was not being parsed by SO.. had to escape it)

Comment: Yea, if your on OSX then Patterns kicks butt! https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/patterns-the-regex-app/id429449079?mt=12

Comment: Sorry, not aware of. But you can try http://regexpal.com/ I have not used it myself, but it may work well for you.

Comment: @enginefree: The above `re.sub()` call is incorrect: [the 4th argument is `count`, not `flags`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). Also you don't need `flags=re.M` unless you use patterns `^` or `$` that are affected by it. Mere [`re.sub(r".*wait.*\n?", "", data)` works](http://ideone.com/N18P5Z) because `'.'` doesn't match a newline without `re.S` flag.

Comment: Nice catch my friend. Updated.

Comment: the regex fails if file ends without a newline. `re.M` does nothing in the regex (no `^`, `$`). `*`s are eaten (interpreted as markdown), try formatting it as code (without `<pre>` tag).